# Django post with data returns a HTTP 403 forbidden error

Tags: django, tastypie

I have started an app to post data to django using tastypie. However, I am getting a http 403 forbidden error. Could you please help me to bypass that error ?

**Edit:**
I am getting that error due to my views.py

```
  </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="summary">
                    <h1>MultiValueDictKeyError at /api/recipes/item_new/</h1>
                    <pre class="exception_value">&#39;Key \&#39;data\&#39; not found in &lt;QueryDict: {u\&#39;{ data:\\n        {\\n          name: &quot;Something&quot;,\\n          content: &quot;Anything&quot;\\n        }\\n}\\n\&#39;: [u\&#39;\&#39;]}&gt;&#39;</pre>
                    <table class="meta">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Request Method:</th>
                            <td>POST</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Request URL:</th>
                            <td>http://localhost:8000/api/recipes/item_new/</td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: It could be a number of things. Is there no logs from your app server that you can check and provide the stacktrace from? apache/uwsgi/gunicorn logs

Comment: I am using Pycharm. Do you know how to get the stacktrace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you hitting a CSRF error? You'll want to add the `csrf_exempt` decorator to your view.

Comment: I added it, but still I am getting an error that is http 500 internal server. Interestingly, If i change my views method to a basic method which is only [def item_new(request):
 return HttpResponse("You did it" )], it works. So, I think, I am having a problem either my data posting way or my "item_new" method. What do you think ?

Comment: What is the 500 error/ what line does it occur on? Do all the keys you are calling on `postdata` exist? You might want to create a Django form to handle validation of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your urls.py you should actually get 404 for this url `/api/recipes/item_new`
Also, your resource is named `recipes` so your first and second urls are exact, which means the second will never get called.

```
url(r'^api/', include(recipe_resource.urls)),
url(r'^api/recipes/$', views.item_new()),
```

Try swithcing the order here and adjust your item_new url like below

```
url(r'^api/recipes/item_new$', views.item_new()),
url(r'^api/', include(recipe_resource.urls)),
```

Comment: I have tried it, nothings changes. What about my calling way, is that correct ?  http://localhost:8000/api/recipes/item_new?format=json { data:
        {
          name: "Something",
          content: "Anything"
        }
}